# Geometric proof concerning circles

Tags: geometry

From a point P outside a circle draw two tangents to the circle touching at points $A$ and $B$. draw a secant line intersecting the circle at points $C$ and $D$. choose point $Q$ on chord $CD$ such that $\angle DAQ$ = $\angle PBC$. prove that $\angle DBQ$ = $\angle PAC$

this is a question of INMO. please prove it in an easy way (if possible)

PS I don't know the year of INMO nor the diagram

Comment: What year of the INMO? Can you provide a link to the original problem statement? Are the angles oriented? in my experiments, I have some trouble satisfying the conditions with oriented angles; $Q$ always ends up outside the circle. A picture would help a lot. You can upload images using the image button above the edit box. For math formatting, [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/35416) is usually a good starting point. In your case, place `$` around each formula (even a single letter) and use `\angle` to write $\angle$.

Comment: I don't know the year nor do I have a diagram.

Comment: Sorry that I don't know these

Comment: Thanks for help on formatting